# array for google map from table html

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps

I have to create the variable ' stops ' from a html table .
the variable stops has this format :
(example)

```
var stops = [
[ ' gussago ' , 45.593741,10.156832 , 1, ' this is gussago ' ]
[ ' Roncadelle ' , 45.530403,10.15101 , 2, ' this is Roncadelle ' ]
[ ' san zeno ' , 45.492691,10.217185 , 3, ' this is san zeno ' ]
.......
] ;
```

the variable is used to create the markers of a path with google map

```
   function setMarkers(map , stops ) {
   for (var i = 0; i < stops.length ; i + + ) {
   var beach = stops [i] ;
   myLatLng var = new google.maps.LatLng (beach [1] , beach [2] ) ;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: myLatLng ,
        map : map ,
        title : beach [0],
        zIndex : beach [ 3]
        html : beach [4]
    });
```

it must be created dynamically from a html table
that looks like this :

```
<table id="lista">
<thead> <tr> <th > ID </ th > <th > lat </ th > <th> Log </ th > <th > name </ th > <th > sentence </ th > </ tr>
</ thead >
<tbody >
<tr id="1"> <td class="name"> gussago </ td> <td class="lat"> 45.593741 </ td> <td class="log"> 10.156832 </ td > < td class = " id "> 1 </ td> <td class="frase"> this is gussago </ td > </ tr>
<tr id="2"> <td class="name"> Roncadelle </ td> <td class="lat"> 45.530403 </ td> <td class="log"> 10.15101 </ td > < td class = " id "> 2 </ td> <td class="frase"> this is Roncadelle </ td > </ tr>
...
<tr style="visibility:hidden;"> <td> < / td > <td> </ td> <td> < / td > <td> </ td> <td> < / td > </ tr>
</ tbody >
</ table>
```

I also have to exclude the 'TR' hidden

I tried to create an array with jquery , but it does not work. this is the code :

```
$ ("#lista tbody ").each(function () {
$ (this).find('tr').each(function () {
index + + ;
arrayOfThisRow [index ] = [];
TableData var = $ (this). find ( ' td ' ) ;
if ( TableData.length > 0) {
tableData.each (function ( ) {
if ($ (this). hasClass ('name ' )) { var name = " ' " + $ (this). text () + " ' " ; arrayOfThisRow [ index]. push ( name );}
if ($ (this). hasClass ( ' lat ' )) { var lat = $ (this). text () ; arrayOfThisRow [ index]. push ( lat );}
if ($ (this). hasClass ( ' log ' )) { var log = $ (this) . text () ; arrayOfThisRow [ index]. push ( log) ;}
if ($ (this). hasClass ( ' id ' )) { var index = aindex ; arrayOfThisRow [ index]. push ( aindex );}
if ($ (this). hasClass ( ' sentence ' )) { var sentence = " ' " + $ (this). text () + " ' " ; arrayOfThisRow [ index]. push ( sentence );}
});
}
});
});
arrayOfThisRow.pop ();
```

arrayOfThisRow the variable must be passed to the function for the variable ' stops '

```
var stops = arrayOfThisRow
```

I hope I was clear

Comment: `var = beach stops [i] ;` This is most probably a typo? What about this `TableData var = $ (this). find ( ' td ' ) ;`? And this: `setMarkers function (map , stops ) {`?

Comment: [example that takes addresses from a table, geocodes them and displays them on the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocodeAddressesFromTable.html)

Comment: Yes, there are typos, they are now correct. my script is correct but it does not work,
thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by building the array inside the function that generates me the google markers, now I have another kind of problem but instead new request.